# Swift Picker Selection composed of View Structs

Tags: ios, swiftui

im new to swift and trying to create a iOS app, where I will display on the bottom of the content view a picker of game cards that are structs, so the user can scroll between them. I don't know why the picker after scrolling to a card keeps coming back to the first card, and how could I fix that, and what is the line that appears on the picker struct. Is there any possibility or method to make the picker go to a desired game card based on a alphabetical column.If anybody has any tips for another possibility of showing views in a circular scroll way could give me a clue please?
Thanks,

The code is down below:

var body: some View {
return VStack {
cardView(cardModel: model.modelPrincipal).frame(width: 300, height: 175, alignment: .top).padding(100)

```
        Picker(selection:
                self.model.doBind()
               , label: Text("picker"), content: {
                cardView(cardModel: self.model.modelCards.first!).frame(width: 250, height: 125, alignment: .center)
                    .tag("First")
                cardView(cardModel: self.model.modelCards.first!).frame(width: 250, height: 125, alignment: .center)
                    .tag("Second")
                cardView(cardModel: self.model.modelCards.first!).frame(width: 250, height: 125, alignment: .center)
                    .tag("Third")
            })

    }
    
}
```

}

This is the Model :
The viewModel are just card structs formed by rounded rectangles.

class cardViewModel : ObservableObject {

```
@Published var model : viewModel = viewModel(principalCard:  cardModel(backgroundColor: .blue, id: 1), cards: [ cardModel(backgroundColor: .blue, id:2 )])

var modelPrincipal : cardModel {
    return model.principalCard
}
var modelCards : [cardModel] {
    return model.cards
}

func doBind()-> Binding<[cardModel]>{
    return Binding {
        self.modelCards
    } set: { new in
        for a in new{
            self.model.append(card: a)
        }
        
    }

    
}
```

and this is the viewModel:

struct viewModel {

```
var principalCard : cardModel
var cards : [cardModel]


mutating func  append(card : cardModel){
    self.cards.append(card)
}
```

}

struct cardModel : Hashable {  static func == (lhs: cardModel, rhs: cardModel) -> Bool {
lhs.id == rhs.id
}

```
func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(id)
}






var backgroundColor : UIColor?
var words : [Word]?
var images : [Image]?
var id : Int
```

}

struct Word {
var position : CGPoint
var size : CGSize
var color : UIColor
var font : UIFont
}

struct Image {
var position : CGPoint
var size : CGSize
//File Manager where the picture is being saved
var url : URL
}

struct Signature{
var url : URL
var size : CGSize
var color : UIColor
var position : CGPoint
}

What I'm trying to do is to display the card struct in a picker form.

Comment: It will be much easier to get help if you provide complete (but minimal) code so someone can run it and see what's happening. See [mre].

Comment: Your edited code is still not reproducible. We don’t have access to self.model

Comment: @jnpdx the model is just a rounded rectangle

Comment: A SwiftUI rounded rectangle doesn’t have a property called modelCards or a method called bind. If you don’t include the relevant code to reproduce your issue, it is impossible to debug.

Comment: As others have said, we can’t really answer your question with the information given. Please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). However, one thing that jumps out at me is that your picker selection is not a bound State variable. It appears to be a function on your model that you haven't posted. That should not compile.

Comment: @Yrb is not that it doesn't compile, im trying to show my cards in a circular mode as the picker shows. I think that is not possible to modify the picker to become as a list of cards, where the user can search. So my question should have been another.

Comment: Have you read the links everyone keeps posting? We are doing this to be able to help you. Until you post sufficient code, we really can't help.